# Dividend and Capital gain taxes for F-1 student

Tags: united-states, taxes, dividends, f1-student-visa

I'm an F-1 student under OPT working full time in NYC. I have a brokerage account with Fidelity. I pay income taxes as a non-resident (1040NR)as I am in F-1 and my F-1 Visa started on 2014.

While opening my brokerage account in Sept 2016, they asked me to fill the W9 instead of the W8BEN even when I mentioned that I am a non-resident. Now, I get a 1099-DIV,1099-B from them. Is this correct? Shouldn't I get a 1042-S or something? This is so that I can claim a lower tax rate on my dividends.